# Is it possible to include external content with php? Is it SEO friendly?

Tags: php, include, external

I need to include an external page into my website. How SEO friendly is this? And which will be the right code to use? I came a accross a few different codes and I'm not sure which to use...

Comment: You can use frames/iframes or with the html "<object>" tag to include external content into your websites. Including it with "include" doesnt work. Dont worry about SEO, Googles algorithm are currently changing into a completely different direction. I found this infographic which pretty much describes the new SEO: http://t3n.de/news/?attachment_id=516037

Comment: @YUNOWORK if there are any changes to the google algorithm, please provide a valid google source

Comment: google barely gives any information about changes in the algorithm, usually ppl only notice it because the searchresults changed. So i wont be able to give you any "valid google source"

Answer (score 1):

Your question as is does not target a specific problem and no code is provided.

You can fetch anything you want and integrate into your website, using output buffers, `file_get_contents()`, SOAP, REST or cURL.

Search engines do not recognize the fetched content as external, but your page load time might increase if you do not buffer the content which decreases SEO value.

The better question is, does the site you want to fetch from allow using of their content, what licence does it have?

Comment: Thank you, I should have added some codes. Sorry if my question wasn't asked right.

Both sites belong to me but the one is on a windows server and the other on a linux server. And I need to include content from my windows server into pages on my linux server.
Basically because I need to give them better URL's, on another domain name. So, the included content HAS be to picked up by search engines on the new domain. So you're saying this is a safe method to use? Google won't pick it up as external content like it does with iframes?

Comment: How should google tell where you have this content from? It is impossible.